# Permalinks by page/post name returning 404

Tags: permalinks, pages, 404-error

All my content is currently setup as pages. I want to setup permalinks with page names. I read some posts online that said choosing %postname% path should render the content. But this does not work. When I access a page, I can see that the link is being updated with the page name, but it returns a 404.

I checked the .htaccess file and httpd.conf. mod_rewrite is loaded and access is setup with the right permissions.

My site is being hosted on ec2 aws.

Update: I just created a post and tested permalinks with it, the post also returns a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697061/wordpress-post-name-permalinks-not-working):

I had to create a custom permalink with the following value:

```
/index.php/%postname%/
```